# jQuery/Javascript basic object property

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Im attempting to create a property called `startPosition` and then assign the `top` property to be the button's `top` value in the CSS.

Here is the jQuery:

```
var morphObject = {

    button: $('button.morphButton'),
    container: $('div.morphContainer'),
    overlay: $('div.overlay'),
    content: $('h1.content, p.content'),

    startPosition: {
        top: morphObject.button.css('top')
        // top: 150,
        // left: '20%',
        // width: 200,
        // height: 70,
        // marginLeft: -100
    },
```

Of course, there is more, but this is where the error occurs. The error is:

```
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'morphObject.button')
```

How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: You forgot to close `morphObject`

Comment: At the point where you are attempting to use it (to assign to `top`), `morphObject` isn't fully constructed.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qwnL3obg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`morphObject` does not exist yet when you call `morphObject.button`.

You could move this outside:

```
var morphObject = {
    button: $('button.morphButton'),
    container: $('div.morphContainer'),
    overlay: $('div.overlay'),
    content: $('h1.content, p.content'),

    startPosition: { }
};

morphObject.startPosition.top = morphObject.button.css('top');
```

OR refer directly to the jQuery element:

```
var morphObject = {
    button: $('button.morphButton'),
    container: $('div.morphContainer'),
    overlay: $('div.overlay'),
    content: $('h1.content, p.content'),

    startPosition: {
        top: $('button.morphButton').css('top')
    }
};
```

Comment: Just a question, why doesn't it exist? You can reference button, container, overlay and content in functions within the object before it's closed. Why not now?

Comment: @George `$('button.morphButton')` already exists, because jQuery has been loaded, so you can call it. But `morphObject` only exists after you close it (So you cannot call `morphObject.button` if you did not finish declaring `morphObject`)

Answer (score 0):

At the point where you are attempting to use it (to assign to `top`), `morphObject` isn't fully constructed. You can define the object completely and then add other properties that depend on already existing property values.

i.e.

var

```
morphObject = {
    button: $('button.morphButton'),
    container: $('div.morphContainer'),
    overlay: $('div.overlay'),
    content: $('h1.content, p.content'),
    ...
};

morphObject.startPosition: {
    top: morphObject.button.css('top')
    ...
};
```

Answer (score -2):

Objects in JavaScript, just as many other programming languages, can be compared to objects in real life. The concept of objects in JavaScript can be understood with real life, tangible objects.

In JavaScript, an object is a standalone entity, with properties and type. Compare it with a cup, for example. A cup is an object, with properties. A cup has a color, a design, weight, a material it is made of, etc. The same way, JavaScript objects can have properties, which define their characteristics.